# A∪B is A or B , or it is A and B?

Tags: probability, elementary-set-theory

I am reading sets and probability so i am having big doubts between A and B  , A or B and A∪B , (A∩B) and A|B .

So what i want to know :

- what is A and B ?
- what is A or B ?
- Is A and B is A∪B ?
- Is A or B is A∩B
- What is | means ? A|B means ?

What is A|B=  B|A means in Bayes theory ?

I am new, so please explain in simple language and also it would also be a great help if you can suggest good websites for learning more about probability for machine learning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$A$ and $B$ are events, i.e., sets of possible outcomes.

Let's take an example. Say you roll a die and record the outcome. $A$ could be the event "the die shows an even number." That means $A$ is the set $\{2,4,6\}$. $B$ could be the event "the die shows a number greater than $3$." Then $B=\{4,5,6\}$.

Now $A$ and $B$, denoted $A \cap B$, is the event that the die shows an even number which is greater than $3$. Thus $A\cap B=\{2,4,6\}\cap \{4,5,6\}=\{4,6\}$.

$A$ or $B$, denoted $A \cup B$, is the event that the die shows an even number *or* a number which is greater than $3$. So $A\cup B = \{2,4,6\}\cup \{4,5,6\}= \{2,4,5,6\}$.

$A\mid B$ and $B\mid A$ are not sets. When we write $P(A \mid B)$, this is read as "the probability of $A$ given that $B$ has occurred" (not "the probability of the set $A \mid B$," as there is no such set). In our example, if $B$ has occurred then we know the die shows $4$, $5$, or $6$. Two of those are even, so $P(A \mid B) = \frac{2}{3}$. In general, $P(A \mid B)$ is calculated using the formula
$$P(A \mid B)= \frac{P (A \cap B)}{P(B)} = \frac{P(B \mid A) P(A)}{P(B)}.$$
The equation $P(A \mid B) = \frac{P(B \mid A)P(A)}{P(B)}$ is called Bayes' Theorem.

---

Edit: Some useful things to know:

- If $A$ and $B$ are *disjoint* (i.e., they have no outcomes in common, so $A \cap B=\emptyset$), then $P(A \cup B)=P(A)+P(B)$.
- In general, $P(A \cup B)= P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B)$. The easiest way to see this is with a Venn diagram. $A \cup B$ represents the outcomes in both $A$ and $B$. So count all the outcomes in $A$, and all the outcomes in $B$, but oops we counted everything in $A \cap B$ twice, so subtract it off.
- If $A$ and $B$ are *independent*, then $P( A \cap B) = P(A)P(B)$. This is often taken as the definition of independence, but intuitively it means that one outcome has no bearing on the other. For instance, if a roll a die and flip a coin, their outcomes are independent. So $P(\text{die is even} \cap \text{coin is heads})=P(\text{die is even})P(\text{coin is heads}) = \frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{4}$.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: but P(A∩B) = P(A) . P(B) then why we don't use this thing in bayes ?

Comment: The formula $P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)$ is *only* true if $A$ and $B$ are *independent*. That is why we cannot use it in Bayes' Theorem. In general (whether $A$ and $B$ are independent or not) we have $P(A\cap B)=P(A \mid B)P(B) = P(B \mid A)P(A)$. Now you can see why another definition of independence of $A$ and $B$ is $P(A\mid B)=P(A)$ (or, equivalently, $P(B \mid A)=P(B)$).

Comment: @tony The Bayes formula is about finding P(A|B) when we know P(B|A). However, please note that when A and B are independent, we will have: P(A|B) = P(A).

Answer (score 4):

I'll demonstrate the connection between $\lor$ and $\cup$, similarly, between $\land$ and $\cap$.

$x \in A\cup B \iff (x\in A \lor x\in B)$. It is in $A\cup B$ if it is A or in B, or in both.

$x \in A\cap B \iff (x\in A \land x \in B)$.  $x$ is in $A\cap B$ if it is in both in A and in B

Comment: OP was asking about conditional probability when they wrote $A\mid B$, not about the set difference $A \setminus B$.

Comment: Your comment, @kccu, is no longer relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Notationally, we have the following: $$A\cup B \implies A or B$$ $$A\cap B \implies A and B$$ $$A|B \implies A given B$$
$A\cup B$ means all elements of $A$ *AND* all elements of $B$, whereas $A\cap B$ means only elements which are in both $A$ AND $B$.

$A|B$ in set theory, is usually $A\cap B$ (someone please correct me if I'm mistaken). However, in probability theory it can be a bit more confusing.